# How to find the point(s) where the tangent line has y-intercept 5

Tags: functions

I have found the derivative of $f(x) = 8/(x^2 +x+2)$.  How do I find the point(s) where the tangent line has $y$-intercept 5?

Comment: ....however if you did have intention of posting on this site, at least give some code showing what you have already tried, and explain what went wrong or why you were not successful.

Comment: And what is "cleared the equation"???

Comment: A single tangent line is (well) a *line* and hence it can have only a *single* $y$ intercept.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] = 8/(x^2 + x + 2);
```

The tangents are located at `x` values

```
soln = Solve[f'[x] x + 5 == f[x], x, Reals] // ToRadicals

(* {{x -> -2}, {x -> (-45 + 2 Sqrt[510])^(1/3)/15^(2/3) - 
    1/(15 (-45 + 2 Sqrt[510]))^(1/3)}} *)
```

The approximate numeric values are

```
solnN = soln // N

(* {{x -> -2.}, {x -> -0.646835}} *)
```

The approximate tangent points are

```
pts = {x, f[x]} /. solnN

(* {{-2., 2.}, {-0.646835, 4.51579}} *)

Plot[Evaluate@Flatten@
   {f[x], (f'[x] /. solnN) x + 5}, {x, -3, 1/2},
 PlotStyle -> {Thich, Dashed, Dashed},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"f[x]", "Tangent 1", "Tangent 2"}, {.2, .8}],
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ pts}]
```

[image]